# Firebase Inserting data into Database three times instead of once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason when I am adding data to Firebase database through a form on my app it saves the data to the database but three times instead of just once as it's supposed to.

I can't quite figure out why because I have used this code before and it has worked fine...

Code:

```
@IBAction func createPostTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            (snapshot) in
              if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                  for user in userDictionary {
                      if let username = user.value as? String {
                          if let game = self.gameTextField.text {
                              if let activity = self.activityTextField.text {
                                if let console = self.consoleTextField.text {
                                    if let skill = self.skillTextField.text {
                                        if let communication = self.communicationTextField.text {
                                            if let lfglfm = self.lfglfmTextField.text {
                                                if let description = self.descriptionTextView.text {

                                                    let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                                        "uid" : uid,
                                                        "username" : username,
                                                        "game" : game,
                                                        "activity" : activity,
                                                        "console" : console,
                                                        "skill" : skill,
                                                        "communication" : communication,
                                                        "lfglfm" : lfglfm,
                                                        "description" : description
                                                        ]

                                                    Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

                                                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Your post was added successfully.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                                                        //code will run when ok button is pressed
                                                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC")
                                                        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                    }))
                                                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea why my code would be posting the data three times instead of once I would appreciate the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is this line of code:

```
for user in userDictionary {
```

Looks like you have 3 entries inside that node so

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)
```

actually executes 3 times.

Comment: I am storing the user's information in a section of the database named 'users', I am trying to get the information of the username from there but for some reason, it is creating three posts due to there being 3 lines of information in there (username, dob, profile image). If I delete the dob and profile image the post is only created once. How can I fix this?

Comment: @DanielJones That `for loop` is unnecessary there. Just remove it and update your code so that you get user data from `userDictionary` instead of `user` object.